# SSIS Project Connection Manager Not Deploying to Integration Services Catalog

Tags: sql-server, deployment, ssis

I created a new project-level connection manager to replace a previous developer's use of a local connmgr. I can see it in my list of connection managers:

[image]

The package deploys to the SSISDB fine. However, when I go to run it (manually executing it), I get a "connection manager not found" error on validation. And when I dig into the project, I find this:

[image]

The new connmgr just isn't there.

The solution was created in Visual Studio 2019, and the SQL Server is version 2019.

I'm not doing anything different from what I've done untold numbers of times in other solutions. In the past everything has copied over without incident. Can anyone shed light on why the new connmgr isn't getting deployed with everything else?